# Chrome proccess stopped before startup complete using chrome-php

Tags: php, google-chrome, headless-browser

I'm using [`chrome-php`](https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome) to automate some feature.

My server is `Ubuntu 20.04`

This is my code:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;

$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory();

// starts headless chrome
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser([
    'headless' => false,
    'proxyServer' => '127.0.0.1:8080'
]);

dd($browserFactory);
```

this will throw exception with this result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Chrome process stopped before startup completed.
> Additional info:
> mkdir: cannot create directory '/.local': Permission denied
>
> touch: cannot touch '/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list': No such file or directory
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
>
> [3350:3350:0831/125919.823336:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY >[3350:3350:0831/125919.823384:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.
>
> Exiting. in /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php:410 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/afsv.ir/v in /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php on line 410

And if I remove options from `createBrowser()` method :

```
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser();
```

I have these errors :

> error: Uncaught Wrench\Exception\HandshakeException:
>
> No accept header receieved on handshake response in /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/wrench/src/Protocol/Protocol.php:469 Stack
>
> trace:
> #0 /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/wrench/src/Client.php(243):
> Wrench\Protocol\Protocol->validateResponseHandshake()
>
> #1 /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Communication/Socket/Wrench.php(99): Wrench\Client->connect()
>
> #2 /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Communication/Connection.php(186): HeadlessChromium\Communication\Socket\Wrench->connect()
>
> #3 /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php(146): HeadlessChromium\Communication\Connection->connect()
>
> #4 /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/BrowserFactory.php(81): HeadlessChromium\Browser\BrowserProcess->start()
>
> #5 /var/www/afsv.ir/index.php(16): HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory->createBrowser()
>
> #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/afsv.ir/vendor/chrome-php/wrench/src/Protocol/Protocol.php on line 469

Does anyone know what wrong in my code or configurations?

***Thanks in Advance.***